# MySQL "Column 'name_a' cannot be null" but there is no null data coming through

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I have a table called `my_table`, which has some fields, one being `name_a` which doesn't allow nulls and when running the following query

```
select * from my_table where name_a is null
```

it returns nothing.

I am copying the data from this table to another table, `backup_my_table` - which also has a field called `name_a`, which also doesn't allow nulls.

The query to copy :

```
insert into backup_my_table
select * from my_table a
where a.id > (select ifnull(max(id), 0) from backup_my_table)
```

I have the same setup running on other dbs, but for some reason on this current db it is now returning this error. I don't understand at all, there are no nulls in `my_table` for `name_a` because it doesn't allow it and the query shows there are none.

Could anyone shine some light on this for me please?

Comment: How are you copying the data from table to table?

Comment: Are you certain that the data you are copying has no nulls for `name_a`?

Comment: Updated question with insert query.
Yeah I'm 100% certain. As i run the query mentioned above which returns no results.

Comment: Have you tried the `INSERT` without the `WHERE` clause as a test? Also what does the `SELECT IFNULL(...)` portion return? To solve these problems you often need to split it up into a series of smaller problems you can tackle individually.

Comment: Are you sure both tables have exactly the same schema (column order for example)? Was there a change on my_table recently?

Comment: I've ran the query without the insert, and the data returned has no nulls - but as I've said, this field wont allow nulls to be inserted - which makes this so odd

Comment: @Galz yeah they are exactly the same

Comment: @user2616166 is the order of the columns also the same? To avoid mapping the wrong columns use the full qualified column names and values e.g. INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...); (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) Try your Insert statement rewriting it that way. It helps.

Comment: this seems like the issue! ive got a few other bugs to sort before I can run this fix, but thank you - will post back